# Why can't I call my Java interface's method?

Tags: java, eclipse, interface

I have declared the following interface in Java:

```
public interface ITest {
    void doStuff();
}
```

which is implemented by another few classes who overwrite the doStuff() method. I then use this interface as the type in a function:

```
public gonnaDoSomeStuff(ITest fun) {
    fun.doStuff();
}
```

However, Java (and Eclipse) state that the method is undefined for type ITest. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you are using *this* `ITest` and not some other interface somewhere else in your project (or your dependencies)? Are you sure that you've *compiled* `ITest`.

Comment: Eclipse's compilied artefacts are likely out of sync with the changes in your file. Save all files, clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: I've cleaned and this is the only file ITest in my project. It still presents the same error...

Comment: What happens when you hold Ctrl and click `ITest` in Eclipse? Does it jump to that `ITest` class? What happens when you ctrl-click `doStuff()`?

Comment: If you click on the ITest parameter whilst holding down the shift button does eclipse navigate to the ITest interface you expect it to?

Comment: Joachim / munyengm: you were both correct. I must have hit quick fix and Eclipse applied a generic of the name <ITest> to my class. It wasn't actually referencing the interface. Thank you!

Comment: @sdasdadas: that's actually a somewhat common problem for beginners (and still I always forget that possibility). You could post this as an answer so future visitors of this question can find it better (and earn some upvotes in the process).

Comment: I will do so only because my local grocery store accepts upvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the class containing my gonnaDoSomeStuff method was appended with a generic, which was being referenced instead of the actual interface.

**Wrong**

```
public class Dog<ITest> {
    public gonnaDoSomeStuff(ITest fun) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Right**

```
public class Dog {
    public gonnaDoSomeStuff(ITest fun) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can not access default declared method in a public class because its scope is limited. You should declared it as public for call in public class.

Comment: This is a good point - but because my subclasses were in the same package this actually didn't pose a problem. But I should have declared it protected for my use-case.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private

Comment: -1 interface methods are always public in Java. Furthermore [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4) states that it is highly discouraged to redundantly specify public modifier in interfaces.

Comment: Am I missing something or is every method declared in an interface public?

Comment: Every method is Public. This can change with the addition of static classes.